# Cannot use an EBS alias as `environmentEndpoint`

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

Creating Route53 Alias record having Beanstalk environment as a target results in the following error:

```
Cannot use an EBS alias as `environmentEndpoint`. You must find your EBS environment endpoint via the AWS console. See the Elastic Beanstalk developer guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html
```

Here's the code:

```js
        const aliasRecord = new route53.ARecord(this, `${config.companyName}-eb-alias`, {
            target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(
                new targets.ElasticBeanstalkEnvironmentEndpointTarget(this.ebEnvironment.attrEndpointUrl)),
            zone: hostedZone,
            recordName: `${config.companyName}-alias`,
        });
```

```
    aliasRecord.node.addDependency(this.ebEnvironment);
```

It seems CDK doesn't support CfnEnvironment.attrEndpointUrl token as the target for ARecord. Since I can't acquire Beanstalk endpoint URL via CDK, I will need to rely on AWS API. I'm thinking to query Beanstalk through AWS API after the resource is provisioned and pass string value to ARecord instead of `attrEndpointUrl` token. There is a problem though, how do I get notified when a particular resource is provisioned? Is there any way to do that in CDK? I can not rely on `addDependency` function as I'm not trying to define dependency between resources, but execute custom code right after the resource is created.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the CDK can help.  A Lambda-backed [CustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources-readme.html#aws-cdk-custom-resources) with an [Asynchronous Provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources-readme.html#asynchronous-providers-iscomplete) is the right tool for this job:

> It is not uncommon for the provisioning of resources to be an asynchronous operation, which means that the operation does not immediately finish, and we need to "wait" until the resource stabilizes

The SDK call is made by one Lambda, while a second, "Waiter" Lambda is periodically invoked to poll the service and report back whether the SDK operation is complete.

You need to write both.  The `custom_resources` provider framework itself will deploy another Lambda that orchestrates the whole process.  The work itself happens cloud-side during the CloudFormation deployment lifecycle.

The [aws-cdk-examples](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/typescript) repo has several Custom Resource examples.